# Activity runs background, although back button is pressed

Tags: java, android, android-activity, back

There is timer in `GameActivity`. After time finishes, end of round activity runs.

When I press back button in `GameActivity`, previous Activity (`MainActivity`) runs. But in background, `GameActivity` is still running. After time finishes, I see end of round activity screen although I am in `MainActivity`.

That means game activity runs in background. How can I stop `GameActivity` when I press back button?

I tried `Finish()` method.

```java
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    Intent i = new Intent(GameActivity.this,GameSettingsActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
    finish();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should stop your timer in the GameActivity's onPause() method. This will ensure your timer is stopped when hitting the back button but also when your app goes in background.

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    //stop your timer here...
}
```